# How to call a function with n parameters, with n set dynamically?

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass the same parameter n times to a function?

For example:

```
if len(menu) == 1:
    gtk.ListStore(str)
elif len(menu) == 2:
    gtk.ListStore(str, str)
elif len(menu) == 3:
    gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)
```

Something like this, but "automatic"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [\*args and \*\*kwargs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```
gtk.ListStore(*[str] * len(menu))
```

Comment: although this is a faitful translation of what stefa has provided in his question, I suspect `str` is meant to be a metasyntactic variable, short hand to emphasize the *number* of arguments, not their content.

Comment: No, this is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure what you mean is:

```
gtk.ListStore(*menu)
```

Sequences can be *splatted* into the positional arguments of a function call.  The splat must go at the end of positional arguments, ie:

```
foo(1, 2, *bar)
```

is OK, but you can't do

```
foo(1, *bar, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def  ListStore(*str_collection): #collect arguments passed into str_collection which is a tuple
    for s in str_collection:
        print(s)

ListStore("A","B","C")
```

Outputs:

```
>>> 
A
B
C
```

`str_collection` has type:

```
>>> 
<type 'tuple'>
```